# Error: validation failed: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "FrontendConfig" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"

Tags: charts, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I am using fronendconfig.yaml file to enable http to https redirection, but it is giving me chart validation failed error. Listing the content of my yaml file. This issue is I am facing GKE ingress. My GKE master version is "1.17.14-gke.1600".

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: "abcd"
spec:
  redirectToHttps:
    enabled: true
    responseCodeName: "301"

Using annotations in values.yaml file like this.

ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    networking.k8s.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: "abcd"
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, `HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect` is in [beta](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages) and only available for GKE 1.18.10-gke.600 or greater as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#feature_comparison).

Since you stated to be using GKE 1.17.14-gke.1600, this won't be available for your cluster.